# "as" followed by "adjective"

Tags: grammar

In the sentences like these:

> I thought of my new watch as crippled.
>
> The girls perceived the school as decisive.
>
> I thought of this as damaged.

Word "as" is followed by adjectives. I knew that it is possible, but I am more familiar with the "as" followed by nouns like "I thought of my new watch as a crippled watch." What makes it possible? Is there a official rule that enables me to do this? Or is ellipsis used?

Comment: It has to be ellipsis. "as **being** adjective"

Comment: @William - Well what about in "The article was printed as edited"?

Comment: @Hot Licks -  as **it was** edited.

Comment: Note that this is governed by the predicate: _think of/perceive/see it as being inadequate_, but not **want/make/like it as being inadequate*, though they're OK without _as_. And, as @William suggests, _as_ is short for _as being_ in this construction.

Answer (score 1):

AS(Adverb) followed by adjective means ("to be/being)

AS(preposition) followed by noun means (for).

However in "as a cripled watch" the sense is more of "as if" than just "as". In reality only " as" should mean ' the role or function a being or a thing performs. Actually the watch was not crippled.